# notation to express $((1+1)^n)^2$ with sigma and r-combination

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$2^n = (1+1)^n = \overset n \sum \limits_{i=0} C(n, i) 1^{n-i}1^i$ by binomial theorem
$ = \overset n \sum \limits_{i=0} C(n, i)$ since $1^{n-i}=1, 1^i=1$

Then if we want to express $2^{2n} = ((1+1)^n)^2$ with r-combination and sigma,  which should we use between $\overset n \sum \limits_{i=0} (C(n, i))^2$ and $(\overset n \sum \limits_{i=0} C(n, i) )^2$?

Comment: obviously the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2^n=\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}\implies \left(2^n\right)^2=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}\right)^2$$

So, the second choice. The first is wrong because $(a+b)^2$ is not the same thing as $a^2+b^2$.